# Returning single string value from API in angular

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an API in .Net Core and I am using it in angular 5 app

Below is My API

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CommonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly CommonUtility util;

    public CommonController(IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
        util = new CommonUtility(_configuration);
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]/{StaffCode}")]
    public string GetUserName(string StaffCode)
    {
        return util.GetName(StaffCode);
    }
}
```

it does return a string value , checked in swagger UI

Now Angular Code

```
GetUserName() {
this.http.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Common/GetUserName/' + this.StaffCode).subscribe(result => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("UserName", result);
  alert(sessionStorage.getItem("UserName"));
}, error => console.log(error));
```

}

Here after calling the API I m getting below output in console

[image]

When I try to store result in session than it give syntax error Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()

How to use output of API here in angular ?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(result)` inside the subscription?

Comment: You can received a full response using {observe:'response'}, see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response. Anyway, if you want to send a JSON you can use in your API: return OK(new {property:value,property2:value});

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using HttpClient your response will automaticaly be assumed to be a json format and before it gets to your subscribe HttpClient will call `JSON.parse()`. Unless you specificaly tell it its not a json. You can do this with `{responseType: text'}`.

```
GetUserName() {
this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Common/GetUserName/' + this.StaffCode, {responseType: text'}).subscribe(result => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("UserName", result);
  alert(sessionStorage.getItem("UserName"));
}, error => console.log(error));
```

When using older versions of Angular you would use the Http class instead of HttpClient. With the Http class this auto parsing from json was not done.